# Eclipse reports syntax error in JSP file, but application works

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, el

I am inspecting codebase of one JAVA project, and I found that Eclipse shows error at the following lines:

```
<c:if test="${not empty queryClauses && ((activeRole eq 'ROLE_ADMIN' && querySearch.project.isPublic()) or (not querySearch.project.isPublic()))}">
    <div class="control-btns">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="updateQuery" value="<spring:message code="query.updateQuery" />"/>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="deleteQuery" value="<spring:message code="query.deleteQuery" />"/>
    </div>
</c:if>
```

Error is being showed at the following place:

```
querySearch.project.isPublic()
```

Error is:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - EL Syntax Error 
    - Encountered " "(" "( "" at line 1, 
     column 87. 
Was expecting one of: 
    "." ... 
    ">" ... 
    "gt" ... 
    "<" ... 
    ...
```

It was written by a co-worker, who has left the company, so I cannot ask Him about it. He assured that it is OK, but I feel bad about seeing an error in Java project.

From searching I found the following comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18417643/508654:

> AFAIR, the latest version of the JSP EL allows calling methods, but
>   your IDE is probably out of date and doesn't expect it. Eclipse is
>   well-known for signalling errors that are not errors at all. Trust
>   your app server.

Is this the same reason? Is there a work-around (by changing project code or Eclipse settings)? Will Eclipse be updated to reckognize the syntax?

Answer (score 5):

Seems to be a longstanding Eclipse validation bug:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=352491

As of writing (2 years after this SO question was raised), it still doesn't appear to have been properly fixed.

Also see the comments in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19340866).

Comment: 8 years later and it's still a problem. That's what we get from using a c̶r̶a̶p̶ free IDE.

Comment: FWIW I've since made the switch to IntelliJ and never looked back.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this line is causing problems, but I suspect you will have a problem with a double quote in a double quote (two lines have this issue) I changed it to have single quotes as follows:
From:
"query.updateQuery"
to:
'query.updateQuery'

Comment: This could also be a problem (and I fixed this), but currently Eclipse is showing error at the following place: querySearch.project.isPublic(). If I remove the parentheses, then the error goes away. My question is that if the method call is allowed at that place?